# Trying to access data from more than one table in a java servlet

Tags: java, sql, oracle

[click here for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tuNl.png)

I have already wasted over a week now experimenting with this and am now looking for help from others... when i execute the query on a single table to get the email id, i get the result but when the query is searching through more than one table it doesn't change the value of my string t (there is no error displayed probably logical)..but the query works fine when i run it in oracle sql developer.

my initial query that works is:

```
SELECT EMPEMAIL 
  from EMP_DATA 
  where EMPID=2000;
```

and query that runs fine in sql dev but not in the servlet(maybe its running fine as there is no error but no change in String t in the code..please check the image) is:

```
SELECT EMPEMAIL 
  from EMP_DATA 
  inner join PO on EMP_DATA.EMPID = PO.STAFFID 
  where PO.EXP < CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: Show both queries, please. And the code that invokes them.

Comment: my initial query that works is "SELECT EMPEMAIL from EMP_DATA where EMPID=2000;" and query that runs fine in sql dev but not in the servlet(maybe its running fine as there is no error but no change in String t in the code..please check the image)is "SELECT EMPEMAIL from EMP_DATA inner join PO on EMP_DATA.EMPID = PO.STAFFID where PO.EXP < CURRENT_DATE;"

Comment: Hi. Please edit the question, and put what was in your comment in the question body.  Too hard to read as a comment.  Please do not post links to code.  Put the code in your question.  What is "CURRENT_DATE"?  This issue does not look like jsp or servlets have any impact on the problem.

Comment: Did you try removing the semicolon at the end? That's not part of SQL, and some JDBC drivers don't like it.

Comment: done @OldProgrammer and i have used CURRENT_DATE for comparing the Expiry date (EXP) of a specific product from product order(PO) table so that i could generate an email alert to that specific email obtained from that query. I haven't called my mail sender bean here(in the screenshot) as it wasn't working because the string's value wasn't updating at all.

Comment: god.. when i read your comment first i laughed a bit because for me forgetting a semicolon has always ended up in an error @TheImpaler but seriously man.. i don't know how but this is really working now.. don't know why.. Thanks for helping everyone !